# Error in kafka server for sockect 127.0.0.1

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to run kafka -storm-cassandra ,in my case tail2kafka itself is a producer and when i start cosumer to consume topic ,it throws below mention error.
please help me out.

Thanks

[2015-05-13 15:28:51,784] ERROR Closing socket for /127.0.0.1 because of error (kafka.network.Processor)
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at kafka.api.ProducerRequest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ProducerRequest.scala:45)
        at kafka.api.ProducerRequest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ProducerRequest.scala:42)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:206)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:206)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range$ByOne$class.foreach(Range.scala:282)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range$$anon$1.foreach(Range.scala:274)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:206)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.map(Range.scala:39)
        at kafka.api.ProducerRequest$$anonfun$1.apply(ProducerRequest.scala:42)
        at kafka.api.ProducerRequest$$anonfun$1.apply(ProducerRequest.scala:38)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:227)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:227)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range$ByOne$class.foreach(Range.scala:282)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range$$anon$1.foreach(Range.scala:274)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:227)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.flatMap(Range.scala:39)
        at kafka.api.ProducerRequest$.readFrom(ProducerRequest.scala:38)
        at kafka.api.RequestKeys$$anonfun$1.apply(RequestKeys.scala:36)
        at kafka.api.RequestKeys$$anonfun$1.apply(RequestKeys.scala:36)
        at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.(RequestChannel.scala:53)
        at kafka.network.Processor.read(SocketServer.scala:353)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

And my Consumer code is

import struct
import time

import kafka.io
import kafka.request_type

class Consumer(kafka.io.IO):

CONSUME_REQUEST_TYPE = kafka.request_type.FETCH

MAX_SIZE = 1024 * 1024

# seconds.
  DEFAULT_POLLING_INTERVAL = 2

def **init**(self, topic, partition=0, host='localhost', port=9092):
    kafka.io.IO.**init**(self, host, port)

```
#: The topic queue to consume.
self.topic        = topic

#: The partition the topic queue is on.
self.partition    = partition

#: Offset in the Kafka queue in bytes?
self.offset       = 1

#: Maximum message size to consume.
self.max_size     = self.MAX_SIZE
self.request_type = self.CONSUME_REQUEST_TYPE
self.polling      = self.DEFAULT_POLLING_INTERVAL

self.connect()
```

def consume(self):
    """ Consume data from the topic queue. """

```
self.send_consume_request()

return self.parse_message_set_from(self.read_data_response())
```

def loop(self):
    """ Loop over incoming messages from the queue in a blocking fashion. Set `polling` for the check interval in seconds. """

```
while True:
  messages = self.consume()

  if messages and isinstance(messages, list) and len(messages) > 0:
    for message in messages:
      yield message

  time.sleep(self.polling)
```

# REQUEST TYPE ID + TOPIC LENGTH + TOPIC + PARTITION + OFFSET + MAX SIZE
  def request_size(self):
    return 2 + 2 + len(self.topic) + 4 + 8 + 4

def encode_request_size(self):
    return struct.pack('>i', self.request_size())

def encode_request(self):
    length = len(self.topic)

```
return struct.pack('>HH%dsiQi' % length, self.request_type, length, self.topic, self.partition, self.offset, self.max_size)
```

def send_consume_request(self):
    self.write(self.encode_request_size())
    self.write(self.encode_request())

def read_data_response(self):
    buf_length = struct.unpack('>i', self.read(4))[0]

```
# Start with a 2 byte offset
return self.read(buf_length)[2:]
```

def parse_message_set_from(self, data):
    messages  = []
    processed = 0
    length    = len(data) - 4

```
while (processed <= length):
  message_size = struct.unpack('>i', data[processed:processed+4])[0]
  messages.append(kafka.message.parse_from(data[processed:processed + message_size + 4]))
  processed += 4 + message_size

self.offset += processed

return messages
```

Comment: We need a little more info than just an error message ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap

Comment: share your consumer code